# Injecting a primitive property in a base class with Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I have got the following interface definition:

```
public interface ICommandHandler
{
    ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    bool SendAsync { get; set; }
}
```

I have multiple implementations that implement `ICommandHandler` and need to be resolved. While Castle Windows automatically injects the `Logger` property, when an `ILogger` is injected, I can't find a way to configure the `SendAsync` property to be set to true by Windsor during the creation of new instances.

*UPDATE*

The command handlers implement a generic interface that inherits from the base interface:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand> : ICommandHandler
    where TCommand : Command
{
     void Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

Here is my configuration:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Register(Component
     .For<ICommandHandler<CustomerMovedCommand>>()
     .ImplementedBy<CustomerMovedHandler>());
container.Register(Component
     .For<ICommandHandler<ProcessOrderCommand>>()
     .ImplementedBy<ProcessOrderHandler>());
container.Register(Component
     .For<ICommandHandler<CustomerLeftCommand>>()
     .ImplementedBy<CustomerLeftHandler>());
```

What ways are there to do this with Castle Windsor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
.DependsOn(Proprerty.ForKey("sendAsync").Eq(true))
```

or with anonymous type

```
.DependsOn(new{ sendAsync = true })
```

regarding updated question, it seeems what you need is along the following lines:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
   .BasedOn(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
   .WithService.Base()
   .Configure(c => c.DependsOn(new{ sendAsync = true })
                    .Lifestyle.Transient));
```

That way you register and configure all handlers in one go, and as you add new ones you won't have to go back to add them to registration code.

I suggest [reading through the documentation](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx) as there's much more to the convention-based registration API than this.

Comment: Thanks @Krzysztof. Must I apply this `.DependsOn` on every concrete command registration, or can I apply this once?

Comment: That depends how you register them. It must make its way to every component but if you register them via convention you write that code once.

Comment: I use 'normal' registration (see my update). Can you point me at example that shows me how to do this through convensions?