# StructureMap: Injecting a primitive property in a base class

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, structuremap

Related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729847/injecting-a-primitive-property-in-a-base-class-with-castle-windsor), but this question is about StructureMap.

I have got the following interface definition:

```
public interface ICommandHandler
{
    ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    bool SendAsync { get; set; }
}
```

I have multiple implementations that implement `ICommandHandler` and need to be resolved. I want to automatically inject these two properties in instances that implement `ICommandHandler`.

I found a way to do inject the `ILogger` by letting all implementations inherit from a base type and the `[SetterProperty]` attribute:

```
public abstract class BaseCommandHandler : ICommandHandler
{
    [SetterProperty]
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public bool SendAsync { get; set; }
}
```

This however, doesn't help me with injecting the primitive `bool` type in all implementations.

The command handlers implement a generic interface that inherits from the base interface:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand> : ICommandHandler
    where TCommand : Command
{
     void Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

Here is my current configuration:

```
var container = new Container();

container.Configure(r => r
    .For<ICommandHandler<CustomerMovedCommand>>()
    .Use<CustomerMovedHandler>()
    .SetProperty(handler =>
    { 
        handler.SendAsync = true;
    }));

container.Configure(r => r
    .For<ICommandHandler<ProcessOrderCommand>>()
    .Use<ProcessOrderHandler>()
    .SetProperty(handler =>
    { 
        handler.SendAsync = true;
    }));

container.Configure(r => r
    .For<ICommandHandler<CustomerLeftCommand>>()
    .Use<CustomerLeftHandler>()
    .SetProperty(handler =>
    { 
        handler.SendAsync = true;
    }));

// etc. etc. etc.
```

As you can see, I set the property for each and every configuration, which is quite cumbersome (however, it is pretty nice that the `SetProperty` accepts a `Action<T>` delegate).

What ways are there to do this more efficiently with StructureMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could use this?

```
container.Configure(r => r.For<ICommandHandler>()
    .OnCreationForAll(handler =>
    {
        handler.Logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
        handler.SendAsync = true;
    }));
```

Comment: Two thumbs up for you! Thank you very much.