# Injecting a property (and overriding constructor setting of same) in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I have a component with a property I'd like to override under certain circumstances.
Short version is--

```
public interface IMyClass
{
  public string SomeValue {get; }
}

public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
   public string SomeValue {get; set;}

   public MyClass()
   {
     //do nothing related to SomeValue
   }

   public MyClass(IHelper helper)
   {
      SomeValue = helper.ReadFromAConfigurationFile();
      //other code follows, unrelated to SomeValue
   }
}
```

Later on, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729847/injecting-a-primitive-property-in-a-base-class-with-castle-windsor) I do..

```
var classParams= new Dictionary<string, string> { { "SomeValue", "A New Value" } }

    Component.For<IMyClass>()
        .ImplementedBy<MyClass>()
        .DependsOn(classParams)
        .Named("NamedInstanceGoesHere")
        .LifestyleTransient());
```

Finally, I resolve my component like this:

```
var myComponent= container.Resolve<IMyClass>("NamedInstanceGoesHere");
```

When I examine `myComponent`, the value of `SomeValue` is as it was set in the constructor and not as I tried to override it.

Is there a way to do what I'm after?  Why `IMyClass` doesn't have a public setter for `SomeValue` and `MyClass` does I'm not sure, but it's probably contributing to my problem...

Comment: If the `SomeValue` property holds a configuration value that is particular to that implementation, why do you expose it in the `IMyClass` abstraction? Why do the consumers of that abstraction need to access that configuration value?

Comment: @Steven good question, that I don't have an answer for. And I don't have the ability to change either the interface or the class.

Comment: Do you have an IHelper registered?

Comment: @PatrickSteele no, I don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the code below, which executes fine without triggering the assertion. Even with IHelper registered. To me it seems you are probably doing something slightly different.

Good luck,

Marwijn.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.Windsor;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class IHelper
    {

    }

    public interface IMyClass
    {
        string SomeValue { get; }
    }

    public class MyClass : IMyClass
    {
        public string SomeValue { get; set; }

        public MyClass()
        {
            //do nothing related to SomeValue
        }

        public MyClass(IHelper helper)
        {
            SomeValue = "hello";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            var container = new WindsorContainer();

            var classParams = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "SomeValue", "A New Value" } };

            container.Register(
              Component.For<IHelper>(),
              Component.For<IMyClass>()
                .ImplementedBy<MyClass>()
                .DependsOn(classParams)
                .Named("NamedInstanceGoesHere")
                .LifestyleTransient());

            var myObject = container.Resolve<IMyClass>("NamedInstanceGoesHere");

            Debug.Assert(myObject.SomeValue == classParams["SomeValue"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for double-checking my work.  Perhaps I oversimiplfied in my example above-- I'll take another pass at this.