# How to implement proper Di with WPF app using Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I would like to use Castle Windsor in my WPF app that is a simple program with 4 controls and two services running. The thing is that I have a service that has a constructor which requires an int parameter.
I've provided installer for CW & and injected it to class but CW fails saying that can't resolve the parameter for the int type.

Part of service constructor:

```
public FaceDetectionService(int devinceIndex)
            : base(devinceIndex)
        {
```

The base service needs parameter to be instantinated.
How should I handle this kind of stuff? I belive something with my understanding is not valid.
If you need any more code, please let me know.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729847/injecting-a-primitive-property-in-a-base-class-with-castle-windsor) may help you find the answer

Comment: @qujck, looks very promissing. Thank you for your contribution :)

Comment: It depends whether your parameter is known in compile time or only in runtime.

Comment: @JanMuncinsky, it's preselected (as the first item of list) at start but then I need to assign user's choice to it. User chooses something from list and its index is being saved to my int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parameter is known only in runtime, then I would recommend to use typed factory:

```
IFaceDetectionServiceFactory
{
    FaceDetectionService Create(int devinceIndex);
}

kernel.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
kernel.Register(Component.For<IFaceDetectionServiceFactory>().AsFactory());
kernel.Register(Component.For<FaceDetectionService>());
```

Then you can inject `IFaceDetectionServiceFactory` and create `FaceDetectionService` in runtime.

More info here:
https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md

Comment: Thank you! That's amazing - the answer that you've provided. I'm gonna follow you instructions.